# Having trouble installing opencv library properly

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

I'm having trouble getting opencv to work in pycharm. I've installed it in the terminal using the pip command and it seems to be installed, however when i start coding i get warning messages when i try use the opencv commands:

```
Cannot find reference 'imread' in '__init__.py'
```

Is there a fix for this?

[image: image of pycharm IDE with code, python packages and warning message]

Comment: this is being asked at least once a week. please take the [tour] and review [ask]

Answer (score 0):

That's not *really* a warning (definitely not in the Python sense).

This just means Pycharm's introspection can't find definitions for that module. This in turn is because it's a compiled module (OpenCV is a C++ project with wrappers for Python) so the "usual" Python source files (for introspection) isn't an option.

For a much deeper discussion and some recent workarounds, see the Github issue on [adding Python typing stubs to OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14590).